# Adding image paths to array using loops and then parsing the paths

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement an image search. I'm looping through images in a folder, adding them to an array, then matching the image paths to the input string and returning it dynamically using jquery, so...

1) Add all images in /path/images/ to array $a[]

2) Parse through image paths for matches to input string

3) add matching paths to $result[]

The comparison looks like this:

```
$result = array();
if (strlen($input) > 0)
{ 
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) 
{
    if (strtolower($input)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($input))))
    {
        array_push($result, $a[$i]);
    }
 }

}
```

That all works... The only issue I'm having is:

When I add the images like this, it can parse it and it works:

```
$a[]="image1.jpg";
$a[]="image2.jpg";
$a[]="image3.jpg";
```

But when I loop through and add to $a like this, it doesn't:

```
$a = glob('../images/all_comics/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Is there a difference between $a[] = "string" and using the glob technique?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so. My goal is to first add all images in path/images/ to an array. Then parse through that array of image paths, comparing the path to the search input.. if something matches... add that to $result[]

Comment: Try `scandir` -- List files and directories inside the specified path

Comment: @HanhNghien Holy crap, that worked! But what's the difference between glob() and scandir()? Why can't I parse through glob the same way I can with scandir?

Comment: The pattern is wrong. Try: `$a = glob('../images/all_comics/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);`. But `scandir` is simple

Comment: @HanhNghien but scandir works perfectly. Why would I want to do glob? What's the difference between scandir and glob?